# Campagnolo Cambio Corsa primitive derailleur -- can it be recreated?

Tags: derailleur, gears, shifter, derailleur-rear, campagnolo

Does anyone make [this sort of system](http://davesbikeblog.squarespace.com/blog/2010/4/26/the-cambio-corsa-campagnolos-early-masterpiece.html) and sell it today, or is my only option looking for someone selling theirs? I've googled whether similar systems are being made today but found nothing to my liking. Are there any new versions of this?

[image: Campagnolo Cambio Corsa]

Comment: What advantages are you looking for? The ability to release the rear wheel while riding? The lack of derailleur pulleys? A four speed close ratio derailleur setup?

Comment: As far as I know, nobody's mad enough to do build this anymore. Note that the frame has to be specifically built for this, so its likely just the bikes that were built this way that use this back in the day.

Comment: You want something with more gears than a fixie/singlespeed but you also want the hipster cred of something really old style?     These gear systems are certainly of historical interest, but are also totally impractical.  Do you really want to loosen your back axle while rolling to change to the other gear?  That's what the top lever does, and the other lever pushes the chain over,  then you retighten your axle and hope its still in line with the brake.   Not really recommended for street usage!   Get an IGH or a deraileur bike if you want gears.

Comment: If it's not being made any more, you should ask yourself why.

Comment: Even if somebody could manufacture the device which might be the easiest bit, it would also require special drop-outs and a special rear axle as well.

Comment: It's definitely easy enough to manufacture, with modern CNC machinery it'd just be a tricky small job so it'd cost more (likely $US1000+ for two dropouts and an axle), but from the photos online it would be straightforward to draw. It's not high precision or anything.

Answer (score 2):

This system, the Campagnolo Cambio Corsa, or race shifter was introduced in 1946 and superseded in 1949 by the Paris Roubaix which used only one lever, vs. two and again in 1951 by the Gran Sport parallelogram derailleur, which slightly modified is still state of the art. The Cambio Corsa was probably only made for three years.

It is still possible to buy these parts, complete systems or bikes with these parts on sites like eBay. Keep in mind that the Cambio Corsa and Paris Roubaix systems require special toothed rear dropouts and can't be used on just any bike.

Even at vintage events like the Eroica it's rare to see them as the gearing is not suited to the routes.